# Call fragment method from another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-tabs, android-annotations

There are a few threads on this topic already, but unfortunately I couldn't solve my problem.

I have 2 tabs. When one tab is finished I want to update another one.

I tried the following in the first FragmentTab:

```
@UiThread
void updateGallery() {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.layout.gallery_layout, new GalleryFragment());
    ft.commit();
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
01-04 02:27:51.805: E/AndroidRuntime(28235): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f030002 for fragment GalleryFragment{41d7dcf0 #4 id=0x7f030002}
```

and

```
@UiThread
void updateGallery() {
    // returns null (ById does also return null)
    GalleryFragment frg = (GalleryFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Gallery");  
    frg.init();
}
```

and I also tried to update the necessary data directly:

```
GalleryFragment gf = new GalleryFragment();
gf.setImageUrls(findDocumentListAll());
gf.getDocumentAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged(); // returns nullpointerexception
```

From what I read so far the problem may be that I never add a `<fragment>` in my `main.xml`(MainActivity.java) but add them in my `MainActivity`like this:

```
MainActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Gallery").setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gallery)));
MainActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Camera").setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.camera)));
mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(MainActivity.this);
```

with the Tab Definition in my Adapter like:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            return new GalleryFragment_();
        case 1:
            return new CameraFragment_();
// ...
}
```

I'm not sure if that matters, but I always use the `android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` and not the `android.app.Fragment;`

Comment: how are those two fragments represented in your app? same activity at once? view pager? sequentially cut into same activity?

Comment: via ViewPager, I edited my post above

Comment: then its easy, change the data in the source, whereever the fragment that displays it, gets it from, and when swiping back to the fragment just reload data from source.

Comment: thats what I'm trying to do, but I cant't do it, because of the exception above. What should I change?

Comment: if the fragment doesnt exist, even better. just create a new one and replace previous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add a method in your activity with this:

```
void updateGallery() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.layout.gallery_layout, fragment).commit();
}
```

And in your fragment, you can call a method from your activity this way:

```
((ActivityMain) getActivity()).updateGallery();
```

Comment: this helped me, my final solution is:
`fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.gallery_fragment, new GalleryFragment_()).commit();`